# How do I keep a polarising filter from coming loose?

Tags: filters, polarizer

I've got a certain lens + filter combination that won't work well together. My polarising filter keeps coming loose when I rotate it.

Is there a trick to keeping it attached, like putting something on the filter threads? I don't want it to get stuck on obviously, but I need to increase the friction between the lens and filter threads.

Comment: If it doesn't move and it should: WD40, if it moves and it shouldn't: gaffer's tape.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd steer clear of anything that makes it actually stickier -- for fear of never separating them again! But perhaps the simplest solution would be to remember to only turn the polariser in the direction that you turn it to screw it in.  ie, only ever clockwise (or counter clockwise, whichever it is)....

Comment: I like the simplicity of this but I was hoping one of the grizzled veterans on this site had some kind of 'magic trick' to share. Ah well, one direction it is. Someone cleverer than I am might invent a ratcheting polarised filter that will only turn one way, like the bezel on dive watches.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to tighten the filter down a little more when screwing it onto the threads. You might need to use a [filter wrench](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0095PQPNM). They are available in a variety of sizes. Having the peace of mind of the correct tool in your bag will help alleviate concern about not tightening it too hard when you instal the filter on the lens. I would avoid any kind of thread compound unless you want to permanently mount the filter.

Comment: +1 for simply tightening it a bit more. I dropped my polarizer (into my hand, lucky me) and after that I did two changes, tighten more and using just light touch on the rotating part only. Sounds obvious, but it took some practicing to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I always turn the polarising filter clockwise (except for small adustments), that way it won't come loose. I have done this for years, with very good results. I don't even have to screw in the filter very tight, because turning it will keep it in place, so there is never any hassle to loosen the filter either.

It takes a bit to get used to, because rotating it counter clockwise seems slightly more natural, but once you do the filter will stay in place.

(Remember that rotating the filter clockwise will be counter clockwise when you are behind the camera.)

Answer (score 0):

Put a rubber band around the outside of the filter.  You'll have to experiment to find the right band.  Too tight, and the filter is hard to rotate. Too loose it comes off.